# D3 Zoomable Treemap changing the children accessor

Tags: d3.js, treemap

I am trying to use Mike Bostock's zoomable treemap  http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/ with one modification. Instead of using nested JSON data, I have have a simple mapping from parents to a list of children. I built a function, getChildren(root), that simply returns root's children, or null if root does not have any children.

I have tried replacing all instances of d.children() with getChildren(d) in the treemap javascript file, but it seems that it is not working properly.

The resulting page shows the orange bar as normal up top, but nothing else displays correctly (i.e. there are no rectangles underneath the orange bar, just empty gray space). All the text from the children is mashed up in the top left corner of the empty gray space, so it might be that coordinates are not being assigned correctly.

Any ideas??
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your code and data?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ErxQh/8/

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do several things at once there, i.e. custom data format and custom layout algorithm. It might be easier to first get one working, then the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there were a few issues here:

- Your data structure doesn't seem to be referencing the child nodes:

  ```
  var nMap = {};
  nMap.papa = {};
  nMap.papa["children"] = [];
  nMap.papa["children"].push({
      "name": "c1"
  });
  // snip
  nMap.c1 = {
      size: 5
  };
  ```

  Unless I'm missing something, your `getChildren` function gets the `{ name: "c1" }` object but never looks up `nMap.c1`. I'm not exactly certain what your alternative data structure is trying to achieve, but it seems like the most obvious option is to use a flat map of nodes, with children referenced by id, like this:

  ```
  var nMap = {};
  nMap.c1 = {
      name: "c1",
      value: 5
  };
  nMap.c2 = {
      name: "c2",
      value: 5
  };
  nMap.c3 = {
      name: "c3",
      value: 5
  };
  nMap.papa = {
      name: "papa",
      children: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
  };
  ```

  With a structure like this, you can map to the real children in the `getChildren` function:

  ```
  function getChildren(par){
       var parName = par.name,
           childNames = parName in nMap && nMap[parName].children;
       if (childNames) {
           // look up real nodes
           return childNames.map(function(name) { return nMap[name]; });
       } 
  }
  ```
- Your children were using `size` instead of `value` to indicate weight, and the rest of the code expected `value` (so they all had weight `0`).
- Because you're using the "zoomable" treemap approach, which uses a specialized version of the treemap layout, you don't need to specify the `.children` accessor of the treemap layout. Instead, use your custom accessor in the the custom `layout` helper:

  ```
  function layout(d) {
      // get the children with your accessor
      var children = getChildren(d);
      if (children && children.length > 0) {
          treemap.nodes({ children: children });
          children.forEach(function(c) {
              c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
              c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
              c.dx *= d.dx;
              c.dy *= d.dy;
              c.parent = d;
              layout(c);
          });
      }
  }
  ```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/WpQCy/

Comment: Thank you! I tried to make a grandchild ("C31") in your fiddle and it seems to behave as it did previously (all names are bunched up at the top left corner). Would you happen to know why this happens?

Comment: Got a solution :) Adding this line to change the default children accessor seems to solve the problem      .children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d.children; })